# Bulk update users with MS graph api v5

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am using Microsoft Graph api to interact with my ADB2C application. I am fetching ,creating, updating and deleting users individually in code and everything is working fine.

Now there is a specific requirement to **update certain fields of several users** and provide it as a feature to admin user. I am using below code as an example that i got from this [link](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/366662e338fcf4edc414fefc8a5dcbc4ad218b90/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md) and this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/batch-requests?tabs=csharp) to bulk update the users in adb2c.

```
        string filterQuery = string.Join(" or ", emails.Select(email => $"mail eq '{email}'"));
        var users = new List<User>();
        var batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContentCollection(graphClient);

        var result = await graphClient.Users.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
        {
            requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = filterQuery;
        });
        if (result != null && result.Value.Count > 0)
        {
            users.AddRange(result.Value);
        }

        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            user.AccountEnabled = !value;
            var userRequest = graphClient.Users.ToPostRequestInformation(user);
            await batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStepAsync(userRequest);
        }
        var response = await graphClient.Batch.PostAsync(batchRequestContent);
        var responses = await response.GetResponsesStatusCodesAsync();
```

Now since this is a post request it fails with exceptions like

> A password must be specified to create a new user.

I changed the `userRequest.HttpMethod = Method.PATCH;` to make it a behave like a patch(update) one but following exception occurs.

> Specified HTTP method is not allowed for the request target.

So the question is how to use the above reference example **to bulk update the users using ms graph api v5**.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any update on this question?

Comment: Yes i had solved it after i asked the question but you have summed it pretty nice for me or anyone looking in future. Thanks.

Comment: thank you very much for your kind response : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var requestBody = new User
{
    OfficeLocation = "22/5555",
};
var requestBody2 = new User
{
    OfficeLocation = "18/6666",
};
var req1 = graphClient.Users["user_id1"].ToPatchRequestInformation(requestBody);
var req2 = graphClient.Users["user_id2"].ToPatchRequestInformation(requestBody2);
var batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent(graphClient);
var userRequestId = await batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStepAsync(req1);
var userRequestId2 = await batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStepAsync(req2);
var returnedResponse = await graphClient.Batch.PostAsync(batchRequestContent);
```

My code worked for me.

Pls allow me to point some of the issues. Firstly, for the [updating user graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request), we only have the option with endpoint

> PATCH /users/{id | userPrincipalName}

Which means with SDK, we could only update user profile for a specific user `await graphClient.Users["userId"].PatchAsync(requestBody)`, but can not with code `var userRequest = graphClient.Users.ToPostRequestInformation(user);`. Your code looks like adding a whole user model into the request and let the api auto detect who is required to update, but this is not doable.

The second issue is that, we are trying to update a user, so the request we need to get is not `ToPostRequestInformation` but `ToPatchRequestInformation` instead.

The third is my own issue, at first I only used `requestBody` for both the request, but after executing the code, I found that `user2` wasn't updated, after I create `requestBody2` for user2, it worked.

The forth is my own issue as well, at first when I tried to update `businessPhones` like what the demo shows, it failed and I test it in postman, I got error message with `Insufficient privileges`, that's because I was trying to update admin user profile, which requires other permissions, [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/users?view=graph-rest-1.0#who-can-perform-sensitive-actions) mentioned it.